# Flexslider change finger swipe angle

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am using flexslider and Joomla to make a mobile swipe responsive CMS site, however the swipe angle required to change from slide to slide is too sensitive. More often than not vertical swiping through the content will activate a horizontal slide. Anyone worked with this and/or have any clue where in the js script i can change the limits of horizontal swiping? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Any progress with this Tim? I'm just starting to explore this myself. A swipe sensitivity pixel value would be ideal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently encountered the same problem and was able to resolve it with this fix:

https://github.com/wearebully/JS-Snippets/tree/master/Flexslider%20Touch%20Sensitivity%20Fix

Hope it helps.